# Poisson arrivals happen in the given interval

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

If $T_m$ is the $m^{\mathrm{th}}$ arrival time of a Poisson process, how to calculate $\mathbb P(T_m < a< T_{m+1} < b)$, where $a$ and $b$ are given times?

Comment: $$
\mathbb P(T_m<a<T_{m+1}<b) = \mathbb P(a<T_{m+1}-T_m<b+T_{m+1}) = \mathbb P(a<T_{m+1}-T_m)\mathbb P(T_{m+1}-T_m < b + T_{m+1}),
$$
by the memoryless property of the exponential distribution.

Comment: @Math1000: That doesn't look right. E.g. consider $a=0$, where the left-hand side is $0$ and the right-hand side isn't.

Comment: Aren't $T_{m-1}-T_m$ and $T_{m+1}$ independent though?

Comment: @Math1000: They are; but I don't see how that justifies either of those two equalities -- certainly not the left one.

Answer (score 3):

The event $T_m\lt a\lt T_{m+1}\lt b$ occurs exactly if there are exactly $m$ arrivals up to $a$ and then at least one arrival before $b$. If the Poisson process has rate $\lambda$, the probability for this is

$$
\frac{(\lambda a)^m\mathrm e^{-\lambda a}}{m!}\left(1-\mathrm e^{-\lambda (b-a)}\right)=\frac{(\lambda a)^m}{m!}\left(\mathrm e^{-\lambda a}-\mathrm e^{-\lambda b}\right)\;.
$$

Comment: Simply brilliant.